# AngularJS intercept all $http requests

Tags: angularjs

I can't seem to get the $httpProvider.interceptors to actually intercept. I created a sample on JSFiddle that logs when the interceptor is run and when the $http response is successful. The request interceptor is run after the response is already returned as successful. This seems a bit backwards.

I can't use transformRequest because I need to alter the params in the config. That part isn't shown in the sample.

I'm using AngularJS 1.1.5

http://jsfiddle.net/skeemer/K7DCN/1/

Javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('httpInterceptor', function ($q) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            logIt('- Modify request');
            return config || $q.when(config);
        }
    };
});

myApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
});

function MyCtrl($scope, $http) {
    // Hit a server that allows cross domain XHR
    $http.get('http://server.cors-api.appspot.com/server?id=8057313&enable=true&status=200&credentials=false')
    .success(function (data) {
        //logIt(data[0].request.url);
        logIt('- GET Successful');
    });

    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
}


// Just the logging
var logs = document.getElementById('logs');

function logIt(msg) {
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.innerHTML = msg;
    logs.insertBefore(e, logs.firstChild);
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">Hello, {{name}}!</div>
<br/>
<div id="logs"></div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The request interceptor isn't running after the data is returned. It's running before. Your logIt function inserts the newest message at the top. If you change your code to use the $log service, you'll see that the interceptor runs first.

Comment: Wow... feeling dumb now. Thanks, though!

Figured out in my other code that I was using the deprecated $httpProvider.responseInterceptors instead of $httpProvider.interceptors.

Answer (score 20):

If you want the option to accept/reject a request at interception time you should be using $httpProvider.responseInterceptors, see example below:

```
$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(function($q) {
    return function(promise){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        promise.then(
            function(response){ deferred.reject("I suddenly decided I didn't like that response"); },
            function(error){ deferred.reject(error); }
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

**EDIT** Didn't read your comment, indeed responseInterceptors is now obsolete an that's how you do it instead:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
    return {
        request: function(config){ return config; },
        response: function(response) { return $q.reject(response); }
    };
});
```

I learned something useful, thanks