# Interceptor not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

Im trying to make a Interceptor in AngularJS. I'm quite new to AngularJS and found some examples of Interceptor, but can't get it to work.

Here I have my app.js file, which have all relevant code. I also have a controller which calls a REST api and get JSONP returned.

First I declare the module and then config it (define the Interceptor). It should now catch all requests and output to console...

Is it wrong to create the Interceptor with app.factory?

```
var app = angular.module(
    'TVPremieresApp',
    [
    'app.services'
      , 'app.controllers'
    ]
);

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('errorInterceptor');
});

app.service('MessageService', function () {
    // angular strap alert directive supports multiple alerts. 
    // Usually this is a distraction to user. 
    //Let us limit the messages to one    
    this.messages = [];
    this.setError = function(msg) {
        this.setMessage(msg, 'error', 'Error:');
    };
    this.setSuccess = function(msg) {
        this.setMessage(msg, 'success', 'Success:');
    };
    this.setInfo = function (msg) {
        this.setMessage(msg, 'info', 'Info:');
    };    
    this.setMessage = function(content, type, title) {
        var message = {
            type: type,
            title: title,
            content: content
        };
        this.messages[0] = message;
    };
    this.clear = function() {
        this.messages = [];
    };
});

app.factory('errorInterceptor', function ($q, $location, MessageService, $rootScope) {
    return function (promise) {
    // clear previously set message
    MessageService.clear();

    return promise.then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    }, 
    function (response) {
      if (response.status == 404) {
        MessageService.setError('Page not found');
      } 
      else if(response.status >= 500){
        var msg = "Unknown Error.";

        if (response.data.message != undefined) {
          msg = response.data.message + " ";
        }
        MessageService.setError(msg);
      }
      // and more
      return $q.reject(response);
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: Which version of angularjs you are using?

Comment: responseInterceptors are deprecated. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/20632690/1014586 to see how you can adapt your code

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`$httpProvider.responseInterceptors` are deprecated. You can modify your code

```
app.factory('errorInterceptor', ['$q', '$rootScope', 'MessageService', '$location',
    function ($q, $rootScope, MessageService, $location) {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                return config || $q.when(config);
            },
            requestError: function(request){
                return $q.reject(request);
            },
            response: function (response) {
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },
            responseError: function (response) {
                if (response && response.status === 404) {
                }
                if (response && response.status >= 500) {
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
}]);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('errorInterceptor');    
}]);
```

See [**Docs**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http) for more info

Comment: @satpal any idea on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590952/keyup-event-alternative?noredirect=1#comment49252528_30590952

Comment: Thanks for the `responseError` interceptor field example. My code was hitting that block when it received a 401 (Unauthorized) when I was trying to implement a jwt token expiration! I was expecting it to hit the `response` block instead on a 401.

[* link to my code if you're interested *](https://github.com/blaskovicz/MagicStick/blob/master/frontend/app.coffee#L150).