# AngularJS - redirect when user lost authorization injector:modulerr error

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Spring Boot for back end of my application. I'm trying to make redirect when user lost authorization during using website or when back end send 401 code to client.

I use interceptor in my config file:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute', 'ngResource','ngDialog', 'tableSort', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'timer', 'config'

]).config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        })
        .when('/main', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        })
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'UserAccount'
        })
        .when('/search', {
            templateUrl: 'views/find_document.html',
            controller: 'findDocument'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

    var interceptor = ['$rootScope', '$q', function(scope, $q) {
        function success(response) {
            return response;
        }

        function error(response) {
            var status = response.status;
            if (status == 401) {
                window.location = "/nologin"
                return;
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
        return function(promise) {
            return promise.then(success, error);
        }
    }];
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
});
```

When I try this code I gets error in console log

Error:

```
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A179)(…)
```

Where is the problem?

EDIT:

Error log from url

```
Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at http://localhost:8080/js/App.js:115:39
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:41:456)
    at d (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:39:418)
    at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:40:19
    at q (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:39:319)
    at cb (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:43:336)
    at c (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:20:390)
    at Bc (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:21:179)
    at fe (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:20:1
```

Comment: do you have the references to all these depdencies in html?

Comment: What exactly? This is my html file https://github.com/MarcinLenda/WzB/blob/master/src/main/resources/static/index.html

Comment: @Sajeetharan I think I have all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to find and replicate your issue, I found out that responseInterceptors are deprecated as this post point out:

[Interceptor not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269007/interceptor-not-working)

So you need to refactor your code.

Hope it helps.