# Is there any object for $http which is equivalent to - $.ajaxsetup?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax

How we can setup common exception handling through `$.ajaxsetup` (same can be use by $.ajax), is there any object which can apply the setup for `$http`.

basically, if token is expired then web api constructor return `401` exception.

so, If possible then I want to apply that globally by setup error event of global object. or any other way then also,please share.

thanks

Comment: You can use Interceptor's, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21269115) might help you

Comment: thanks. it works. you can add in answer.