# How to intercept all http requests using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

My Question is a bigger and broader version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995172/angularjs-intercept-all-http-requests). I want to intercept **all** http requests issued inside an AngularJS function. Later I need to alter the request URL and than pass it to the server..

How can I do that ? So far I have used $httpProvider and $q to create a interceptor but I am only able to intercept only $http requests not all the requests i.e. **if someone clicks on any href link on my page etc**. My interceptor code is :-

```
// register the interceptor as a service
myModule.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function ($q) {
    return {
        // optional method
        'request': function (config) {
            // do something on success
            console.log("request success");
            return config;
        },
        // optional method
        'requestError': function (rejection) {
            // do something on error
            console.log("Request Error");
            if (canRecover(rejection)) {
                return responseOrNewPromise
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        },
        // optional method
        'response': function (response) {
            // do something on success
            console.log("Response received");
            return response;
        },
        // optional method
        'responseError': function (rejection) {
            // do something on error
            if (canRecover(rejection)) {
                return responseOrNewPromise
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});
myModule.factory('myInterceptor', ['$log', function ($log) {
        $log.debug('$log is here to show you that this is a regular factory with injection');

        var myInterceptor = {
        };

        return myInterceptor;
    }]);
myModule.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Intercepting navigation to other pages is different from intercepting http requests. Maybe what you want is to intercept $location changes.

Have a read through this. You can do it but it depends on where the location changes are to.

http://uiadventures.wordpress.com/2013/09/06/routechange-angularjs/